# Excel VBA: Selecting a range from a worksheet and use this data inside a form

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to use a range to populate my combobox inside a form I've created. Now I can statically add items using the addItem method, but what if I have tables across various worksheets that contain the description and values - and want to use these as the source for the form.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim c
For Each c In Range("A1:A4")
    ComboBox1.AddItem c.Value
Next
```

Hope this helps.